# Webpack, CSS, and image files

Tags: javascript, css, npm, webpack

We just switched to webpack recently. We're still learning the ins and outs.

I downloaded a 3rd-party library that comes with minified javascript, CSS, and 10-12 (SVG) image files. The CSS refers to these image files.

When we build our bundles for deployment, they do not include the image files.

See below:

```
stepper-left.svg:1 GET http://localhost:9080/mw44/bundles/styles/stepper-left.svg 404 (Not Found)
stepper-play.svg:1 GET http://localhost:9080/mw44/bundles/styles/stepper-play.svg 404 (Not Found)
stepper-right.svg:1 GET http://localhost:9080/mw44/bundles/styles/stepper-right.svg 404 (Not Found)
```

From other bits that I've read on stackoverflow, it appears possible to encode these images (base64) and store them in the bundle. For a variety of reasons, I'd prefer not to go down that patch unless it is necessary.

So, my question is: are there other ways to handle images with webpack?

Also, I am concerned about the URLs for fetching the images. Short of editing the CSS files, is there a way to better control the fetch URL for each image?

Answer to question: Relative URLs. See below:

```
.SequenceStepNextHighlight .SequenceComponentIcon {
    background-image: url('./stepper-right.svg');
}
```

Comment: How is the library's CSS referring to these files? Absolute paths?

Comment: @Nick Answered your question within the body. Thanks!